# Project looking for own DLL in another project

Tags: .net-4.5, visual-studio-2019

I'm currently trying to move a solution with multiple projects from VS 2015 to VS 2019.It consists of one application and a couple of class libraries, target framework for each is .net 4.5.1. I have made a local copy of the solution to do this.
Most of the projects compile without a problem, but some of the one that are used as AddIns for the application don't. 
When trying to build, doesn't matter if the projects by themselves or the whole solution, it fails because it's looking for itself. In my example picture, the project ZZ_WPF_Bank_AddIn is, while trying to build, is looking for the ZZ_WPF_Bank_AddIn in the bin folder of another project in the solution.
I tried just copying the dll from the original project, to see what happens, but it just points to the same dll missing in another project.
Has someone encountered this behaviour before? I tried googling it, but couldn't find anything useful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTpBu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might stumble upon this:

The solution to my problem was removing all references to projects inside the solution and adding them via Browse, noch via the projects tab on the left side. For some reason the bindings were not working properly after the migration.